# Agricultural society—meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In its early years,this country had an **agricultural society**.

What's the meaning of the bolded text in this context, I know society here **mean  particular group of people**.

Comment: It feels like you've answered your own question. It's group of people who are all involved or interested in agriculture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An agricultural society would be a group of people who live on farms and are mostly focused on farming to live. This would be different than, for example, an industrial society, which would have a big focus on manufacturing or production.